# Angular Global Service recreated every time I manually switch between components

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a service called `GlobalserviceService` and two components `FirstComponent` available under the path: `http://localhost:4200/first/app` and `SecondComponent` available under the path `http://localhost:4200/second/app`. Each time I type new URL to switch from current component to the other one, my `GlobalserviceService` gets recreated (constructo is called) so I lose all data stored previously in it. Is there a way to prevent that from happening? The Sample app is stored in git repository `https://github.com/rejkid/test-app.git`

Comment: Post your service, components and modules.

Comment: It's actually not the service that gets recreated, your entire app gets recreated! you're navigating through the browser, it's like closing the tab and reopening it again, if you want to keep the data in such scenarios use `localStorage` API.

Comment: Rana_S I have git repository at (https://github.com/rejkid/test-app.git) with my components there.

Comment: Are you saying it prints “GlobalserviceService created” every time you navigate?